# Can i copy my Heroku deployment and its commit history to a new github repository?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm wondering if it's possible to copy my Heroku deployment, along with its commit history to a new repository in github. I want to upload the code to my account and include all its history rather than having just one commit. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you lost the original Github repository?

Comment: No, but I had been pushing my commits to Heroku only. Wanted to get it on my github too with all the commits so people can view it.

Comment: In that case, fire up a Github repository for it, and follow their instructions for connecting it to an *existing* local Git repo (the one you already have locally).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to copy my Heroku deployment, along with its commit history to a new repository in github. I want to [preserve] all its history ..

Yes.

Use something like `git remote -v` to find the URL of your repository at heroku. It might look like this:

```
origin  git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git (push)
prd     https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (fetch)
```

If you can't use `git remote` you can guess the URL using the name of your app.

Then `git clone https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git`.

Now you can push your local copy to git with the usual github routine.

Comment: ...but [don't make a habit of it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub." I know OP is asking how to clone specifically so they can put it on GitHub, but this might be a useful note for future visitors.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. Appreciate the link and the explanation guys!